# Из каких помещений состоит ресторан?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какие помещения включает ресторан? Одно из них - кухня, а второе? Зал? Зал для гостей? Какие еще есть аналоги названий?

Answer (score 3):

Вестибюль с примыкающими гардеробом и туалетными комнатами, один или несколько (банкетных) залов, бар, кухня. В зале может быть танц(евальная) площадка (на молодёжном жаргоне "танцпол"). В некоторых ресторанах восточного (южного) типа в зале может располагаться плита или мангал для приготовления пищи на глазах у посетителей.

Answer (score 0):

Трапезная. Правда, это слово слегка устарело.

Comment: Трапезная в обычном ресторане? Думаю, что это неправильно. _Тра́пезная (устар. тра́пеза) (др.-греч. τράπεζα — стол) — церковное помещение (часть храма, хозяйственного здания или отдельно стоящая постройка) для совместного приёма пищи, богослужений, а также общественных нужд._ https://illustrated_dictionary.academic.ru/11882/Трапезная

Answer (score 0):

[На заметку бизнесмену](https://vosstroi.ru/stati/article_post/kakiye-pomeshcheniya-dolzhny-byt-v-restorane)

> Процедура приема гостей заведения начинается в вестибюле, оснащенном
> стойкой ресепшен. Неподалеку должна находиться гардеробная комната для
> верхней одежды посетителей. Основным торговым помещением ресторана
> является обеденный зал. Гостям заведения должны быть доступны туалеты
> для мужчин и женщин.
>
> Группа производственных помещений включает в себя цехи для:
>
> приготовления горячих и холодных блюд; мойки посуды; изготовления
> выпечки; обработки полуфабрикатов. К вышеуказанной категории помещений
> также относятся склады для хранения продуктов, холодильные камеры,
> раздевалки для поваров, а также кладовые для кухонного инвентаря.
> Производственное назначение имеют и буферные зоны для разгрузки тары с
> продовольствием.
>
> Далее следует ознакомиться с перечнем технических помещений. Ресторан
> должен быть оборудован комнатой для обслуживания вентиляции, а также
> узлом, в котором расположен щит распределения электроэнергии.
> Заведение может иметь собственную котельную в случае, если отопление в
> здании является автономным. Автоматизированные рестораны должны
> оснащаться комнатой для сетевого оборудования.
>
> Кроме того, в любом ресторане необходима группа
> административно-бытовых помещений. Для поваров и официантов должны
> быть предусмотрены уборные комнаты с туалетом и душевыми кабинами.
> Охрана заведения осуществляется с использованием наблюдательного
> пункта, который, как правило, располагается возле вестибюля. Также в
> здании должны быть предусмотрены комнаты для отдыха персонала и
> кабинеты для директора и бухгалтерии.

---

[Вестибюль – помещение, с которого начинается обслуживание потребителей](https://studfile.net/preview/2581651/page:14/),

> включающее гардероб, вход в зал, туалетные комнаты.
>
> Площадь вестибюля должна быть равна 1/4 площади зала, из расчета
> 0,3–0,45 кв. м на одно место. Вестибюли в зависимости от площади,
> бывают малыми, большими и аванзалами. В них размещают информацию об
> услугах и необходимые указатели.
>
> Малый вестибюль должен иметь площадь не менее 50 кв. м. в том случае,
> если ресторан на 400–600 мест, то площадь вестибюля 100 кв. м. В
> некоторых ресторанах в вестибюлях организуют продажу газет, сигарет и
> сувениров.
>
> Аванзал – продолжение вестибюля – обставляется мягкой мебелью,
> диванами, кушетками, журнальными столиками с печатной рекламной
> продукцией. Должен, как и вестибюль, освещаться естественным светом.
>
> Гардероб – помещение, предназначенное для приема верхней одежды. Он
> оборудуется шкафчиками для хранения обуви, а также одно- и
> двухсекционными вешалками с раздвижными контейнерами, крючки
> располагаются на высоте 1,5 м от пола.
>
> Туалетные комнаты должны быть безукоризненно чистыми, с холодной и
> горячей водой, в них должно быть все необходимое для мытья и
> обсушивания рук, поправки прически и т.д. В туалетах должны быть
> активная вентиляция и хорошее освещение. В кабинках необходимо наличие
> туалетной бумаги и аэрозольных дезодорантов. Желательно иметь в
> туалетах одежные и обувные щетки.
>
> В курительных комнатах размещают мягкую мебель, пепельницы на ножках.
> Для отделки используют невоспламеняющиеся материалы, применяют
> интенсивную вентиляцию. Кроме общеобменной вентиляции рекомендуется
> установить вытяжку.
>
> +Зал ресторана – это помещение, где обслуживаются потребители. Он должен располагать к отдыху и оказывать определенное психологическое
> воздействие на человека. Зал является центром в архитектурном решении
> ресторана, здесь необходимо сочетать все элементы оформления:
> сервировку и оформление блюд, цветовое и световое решение интерьера.
> Зал должен быть удобно связан с раздачей, сервизной, моечной и
> буфетом. Отношение длины зала к ширине может быть от 2/3 до 1/3. Если
> площадь зала большая, то обязательно освещение с двух сторон. Глубина
> естественного освещения не должна превышать 9 м. Нужно исключить
> пересечение движения официантов с готовой продукцией и использованной
> посудой.
>
> Расположение танцевальной площадки зависит от размера и композиции
> зала. Она может быть в центре зала, заканчивать перспективу зала.
> Обычно ее выделяют с помощью светильников, особой формой потолка. В
> ресторане норма площади для эстрады и танцевальных площадок составляет
> 0,15 кв. м на одно место, глубина эстрады от 3 до 8 м.

Answer (score 0):

Помещения в ресторане, где непосредственно обслуживаются клиенты, - **зал и кабинеты**.
Что касается "бара", то это, строго говоря, не помещение, а место.

Ограничусь этим, все остальные свединия, боюсь, не имеют прямого отношения к вопросу.